# Can't get my DropDownListFor to select a selected SelectListItem item in a Dropdown menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, model-binding

I have a collection of items populated to a drop down menu:

```
string myUserName = "PopulatedWithSomeUser";

var users= from x in userRepository.GetAll()
    select new SelectListItem
       {
          Value = x.Id.ToString(),
          Text = x.Name,
          Selected = (x.Name == myUserName )
       };
```

This correctly populates an object and sets the selected item.
Next I pass this to my View with a ViewModel and try to Populate/select:

I tried:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Users,new SelectList(Model.Users),new {id = "add-user-list", name="add-user-list"})
```

also

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Users,new SelectList(Model.Users,"Value","Text","Selected"),new {id = "add-user-list", name="add-user-list"})
```

also

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Users,Model.Users, new {id = "add-user-list", name="add-user-list"})
```

The list is populated correctly but my "selected" item is never selected.
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first parameter you should pass a field for what you are going to receive data after form submit. Everything else looks right:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.UserId, Model.Users)
```

Or if you are going to provide your own id and name - it would be better to use this ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)):

```
@Html.DropDownList("add-user-list", Model.Users, new {id = "add-user-list"})
```