# LINQ distinct to @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, linq, razor

Ok I am having a lot of trouble for something I think should be pretty easy.  I am trying to populate a dropdown list with distinct values from a table.

This linq provides the list of departments I need for each drop down option.

```
IPACS_Master_Lists
   .Where (x => (x.Department != null))
   .Select (s => s.Department)
   .Distinct ()
   .Select (v => v)
```

How do I make a dropdown list with this?

I've tried messing with @Html.DropDownList but cannot get anything to work it seems.

My controller is as follows.  I tried to pass it in with ViewBag but couldn't get that to work either.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var docs = db.IPACS_Master_List;
            ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(db.IPACS_Master_List.Where(x => (x.department != null)).Select (s => s.department).Distinct().Select (v => v), "id", "department", 0);
            return View(docs);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `ViewBag`, everytime you use it a kitten dies.

Seriously, it is **really** bad practice.

First, assuming this in your Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public List<Documents> Docs { get; set; } //don't know what type this is
   public List<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
   public string Department { get; set; } //this holds what you select in the view
}
```

Then change your action to be:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    model.Docs = db.IPACS_Master_List;
    model.Departments = db.IPACS_Master_List
       .Where(x => x.department != null)
       .Select(s => s.department)
       .Distinct()
       .Select(s => new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = s.Name,
               Value = s.Name
           })
       .ToList();

        return View(model);
}
```

Then have your view use the model `MyModel`.

Then you can do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.Departments)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without an ID field?  All I really need is the Department name to show up in the drop down list.  So I would just set up a model to just have one property departments?

Comment: @JamesWilson That's entirely possible. Check my updated edit. It just uses the department name as both the text and value on the drop down list. Then the model just has the name.

Comment: Don't worry, I took care of the kitten for this use of ViewBag.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your collection into a collection of `<SelectListItem>`

```
var myResult = IPACS_Master_Lists.Where (x => (x.Department != null))
   .Select (s => s.Department)
   .Distinct ()
   .Select (v => new SelectListItem{
    Value = v.ResultIdField,
    Text = v.ResultNameField
    })
```

Then link it to the actual dropdown list:

If you're passing via a ViewModel:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedResultId, @Model.myResult ,"- Select One")
```

If you're passing your collection via ViewBag ( I would stay away from this ):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedResultId, @ViewBag.myResult ,"- Select One")
```

Another option for you if you don't have a ViewModel in the view at all:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectListName", ViewBag.myResult, new {id = "selectListId"})
```

Also check out my question I asked here about a year ago. It should help you:
[Can't get my DropDownListFor to select a selected SelectListItem item in a Dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039621/cant-get-my-dropdownlistfor-to-select-a-selected-selectlistitem-item-in-a-dropd)

Comment: Could not get this method to work.  It seems to break down in the last Select with v not finding anything.  It's like Intellisense doesn't link v to anything.

Comment: Do you have "SelectedResultId" in your Viewmodel or do you not have a model on the particular View at all ? Is ViewBag the only source of data ? Also, I updated the answer

Comment: Yeah I don't have a model for this particular piece of data.  I'm unsure how to do this because this particular view already has a model.  When you first visit the page it shows the entire table, and has a drop down, selecting this drop down I want to use it to filter the results.  The drop down contains data that is inside of the table a distinct list of all departments.