# Get selected item of DropDownListFor and using it to create new list

Tags: c#

Have some problems trying to solve this. Have two DropDownListFor where the first is populated with data and the second should be populated using the selected value from the first.

Lets say the first DropDownlist contains these data:

**RoutesList;**

```
Value = "CoOs", Text = "Copenhagen - Oslo",
Value = "StOs", Text = "Stockholm - Oslo",
Value = "OsCo", Text = "Oslo - Copenhagen"
```

In my razor view I'm trying to create a new list based on the selected value.

How do I get the selected value, lets say "StOs" and format it so it only contains the first two letters "St"? Trying to do this with C# and not Jquery.

**My code**

```
// Loads RoutesList to departureRouteSelectList
var departureRouteSelectList = Model.RoutesList;

// Finds selected value
var selectedItem = departureRouteSelectList.Select(x => x.Value);

// Create new selectList for returnRoute
List<SelectListItem> returnRouteSelectList = null;
```

I'm not sure if the "Select" command does what I want and getting the "StOs"?

Comment: You want to change text of first dropdown right?

Comment: departureRouteSelectList.Select(x => x.Value) only gives the list of values.   List<string> containing "CoOs", "StOs", "OsCo". First you need to get the selected value from dropdown list and then do departureRouteSelectList.Select(x => x.Value == selectedValue)

Answer (score 0):

Understanding what you want make me think this post will resolve your problem:

[Can't get my DropDownListFor to select a selected SelectListItem item in a Dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039621/cant-get-my-dropdownlistfor-to-select-a-selected-selectlistitem-item-in-a-dropd?rq=1)